# POST returns 415 (Unsupported Media Type)

Tags: angularjs, rest

I believe I am setting the right data type on both resource and http request, but For some reason I am still not hitting the REST method, but getting back 415 errormessage.

REST Method:

```
@POST
@XmlElement(name = "query")
@Path("/query")
@Consumes({ "text/turtle" })
@Produces({ "text/turtle" })
public Response query(Query query) {...}
```

Angular HTTP request

```
$scope.searchContact = function (q) {
        var uri = $scope.path;
        $http({
          method: 'POST', 
          url: uri,
          data: q,
          headers: {
            //'Content-Type': 'text/turtle',
            'Accept': 'text/turtle'
          },
          withCredentials: true
        }).
        success(function(data, status, headers) {
          if (status == 200 || status == 201) {
              $scope.queryResult = data;
              //$("#query").val(data);
              $scope.searchcontact = {};
          }
        }).
        error(function(data, status) {
          if (status == 401) {
            notify('Forbidden', 'Authentication required to create new resource.');
          } else if (status == 403) {
            notify('Forbidden', 'You are not allowed to create new resource.');
          } else {
            notify('Failed '+ status + data);
          }
        });
    };
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**SOLVED:**

I am sending a String but expecting Query object. So once changed that to String and it all worked!

Comment: It looks like your REST method only accepts text/turtle input as the request body. Since you commented out the content-type header of the angular request, it's probably defaulting to text/plain or something dependent on your data. Then the 415 would be your server informing you that it doesn't accept a request body from that type. Have you tried uncommenting that line, or setting the @Consumes directive to the actual content-type of your request body?

Comment: @Fasermaler, yes I did try uncommenting. It gives the same error.

Comment: Weird, have you tried checking the network request using browser tools (F12) to see which content-type it actually specified for the request?

Comment: Yes of course, the Content-Type in both request and response headers are the same.